# SwiftUI Trying to find a value into an Array and save it into a Var

Tags: arrays, search, swiftui, func

I've an Array based on this struct :

```
struct Airports2: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable{
    var AirportID: String = ""
    var Icao: String = ""
    var ApType: String = ""
    var Name: String = ""
    var Latitude: String = ""
    var Longitude: String = ""
    var Altitude: String = ""
    var Continent: String = ""
    var Country: String = ""
    var Region: String = ""
    var Municipality: String = ""
    var Service: String = ""
    var GpsCode: String = ""
    var Iata: String = ""
    var LocalCode: String = ""
    var Link: String = ""
    var wikiLink: String = ""
    var Keyword: String = ""
    let id = UUID()
}
```

And I would like to create a function which have as Parameter a String corresponding to the ICAO and from the ICAO find the airport Latitude and save only the Latitude in a simple var and return it.

My Airport array is declared as follow :

```
var FR_airportsDB = [Airports2]()
```

And my "searching function" is like that :

```
func getApLat(ApName: String) -> Double{
    
    let LAT: Double
    
    var latFindString = FR_airportsDB.contains(Airports2.init(Icao: ApName))
    
    LAT = Double(latFindString)!
    
    return LAT
}
```

But this is not working, I think `.contains` is not the best to use but I don't know how to make a search in a structured array.

Hope to be clear about my problem ..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please name your variables lowerCamelCase according to the naming convention and name your struct in **singular** form

```
var frAirportsDB = [Airport2]()
```

To search for a value of a specific property try to get the `first` item in the array `where` the value of this property `is equal` to the value in the parameter.

You have to return an optional because the item might be not available and the string could not be converted to Double

```
func getApLat(apName: String) -> Double? {
    
    guard let foundAirport = frAirportsDB.first(where: {$0.Icao == apName}),
          let lat = Double(foundAirport.Latitude) else { return nil }
    
    return lat
}
```

And please add CodingKeys to convert the uppercase keys to lowercase property names. And all default values in the struct are not necessary. The code compiles even without.

Comment: Hey, many thanks for your answer ! I haven't think abut `.first` ! This work very well ! Sorry about the syntaxe :D I know that I need to do it better but I'm not perfect for now !